# jQuery keep cursor to beginning of text input until user starts typing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to mimic twitter bootstrap's text input behavior. I noticed in Twitter Bootstrap's inputs the cursor always stays at the beginning of the text input when a user clicks there. But the "Search" text doesn't disappear until the user starts typing.

I've got most of it working except for me the cursor doesn't stay at the beginning of the text input. Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Here's my jQuery code so far:

```
$('input[title]').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === '') {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
    }
    $(this).keydown(function() {
        if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
            $(this).val('').removeClass('blur');
        }
    });
    $(this).mousedown(function() {
        if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
            $(this).blur().val('');
            $(this).focus().val($(this).attr('title'));
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('blur');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Btw for newer browsers u can use placeholder attr instead of title

Comment: just updated my answer and jsbin link, i think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will surely help you: http://jsbin.com/ohoyer/2/edit

```
jQuery(function ($) {
       var $inputExample = $('#input-ex');
       var a = false;
       $inputExample.click(function () {
         $inputExample.caretToStart();
       });

       $inputExample.keypress(function(){
       if(a == false){
         $(this).val('');
         a = true
       }else{
         $inputExample.caretToEnd();
       }
    });
});
```

This is the plugin used for this:

```
`https://gist.github.com/DrPheltRight/1007907/raw/
  b1ce3b710616f9ee15a6b8ca2b03e35756d3d816/jquery.caret.js`
```

Comment: Thanks Jai! While I agree that using the placeholder attribute is probably best practice, I was in fact looking to learn how to do this with just javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1):

What you described might be an attribute called placeholder:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something…">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add focus to the input

```
$("#inputid").focus ();
```